# How to use a NextJS Template as React Single Page Application

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've bought an admin template that was supposed to be in react, but came with a nextjs project inside. I've ran npm run build && npm run export , then hosted the files at S3 behind a CloudFront domain that forwards all requests to the index.html file.

There are many routes in the app, like /, /home, /account, /users... but when I land at url/account, or any other, it always redirects me to the /home. It doesn't seem to be able to hold the url and redirect the according page, even if its not protected route.

I've also read that nextjs is intended to be rendered server-side, but as I said, I'm hosting it from a static source, S3. So when I use npm run dev the arrival routes work. But I can't use this command in s3.

So can I use a nextjs project in the form of a pure client side rendered single page app similar to how one would use a react-app? Serving from S3 as static site with all requests going to /index.hml?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a Next.js project as a pure client-side rendered single page app (SPA) and serve it from S3 as a static site with all requests going to index.html. However, you may need to modify your Next.js configuration to enable client-side routing.

Next.js uses server-side rendering (SSR) by default, but it also supports client-side rendering (CSR) through its built-in routing system. To enable CSR, you can set the exportPathMap function in your next.config.js file to return an object that maps your routes to their respective pages. For example:

```
module.exports = {
  exportPathMap: async function () {
    return {
      '/': { page: '/' },
      '/home': { page: '/home' },
      '/account': { page: '/account' },
      '/users': { page: '/users' },
      // add more routes here
    };
  },
};
```

This tells Next.js to generate static HTML files for each of your routes, which can be served from S3. When a user navigates to one of these routes, the app will use client-side routing to render the appropriate page without a full page refresh.

If you're still experiencing issues with client-side routing, it may be related to how your CloudFront distribution is configured. Make sure that the CloudFront origin domain is set to your S3 bucket and that the default root object is set to `index.html`. You may also need to configure CloudFront to allow HTTP methods other than GET and HEAD, as Next.js uses the `OPTIONS` method for client-side routing.

Overall, while Next.js is optimized for server-side rendering, it is still possible to use it as a client-side rendered SPA. With the right configuration, you can serve your app from S3 and enjoy the benefits of client-side routing without the need for a server